# Discontinuous selection in Firefox?

Tags: macos, firefox, selection

According to this site https://testkeis.wordpress.com/2008/07/10/discontinuous-selection-in-firefox-3/ you could do discontinuous selections in old versions of Firefox. I have tried different keyboard combinations but fail to achieve the result described in the article, but I use a Mac which complicates things.

Is it still possible to perform discontinuous selections in Firefox?

(I want to do that so I can highlight different parts of a text before making a screenshot)

Comment: I am able to do it on Windows with Firefox. I don't have access to a Mac at the moment but I use the Ctrl key and cursor to highlight different sections. The Command key (⌘) is usually used in place of Ctrl. Does holding the Command key and using the cursor to highlight work?

Comment: Try also the Meta key.

Comment: Mac doesn't have a Meta key.

Comment: Thanks for this useful tip! Ctrl-Cmd + drag works on Windows, and in LibreOffice *Writer*, as well! (Now, I can use that, along with Alt-drag for selecting a rectangle.)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  + left-mouse-button click/drag.
This must be a Firefox only structure. I've never heard of it being possible before now.

> [image]

Comment: I've used this practice in other software, specifically text related editors. Possibly this method is not limited to Firefox.

Comment: I tried that before asking but it didn't work, but now when I try here at SE it works. I think I tried it on Gmail or Facebook and they are notoriously weird when it comes to many basic functions!

Comment: Double checked, yes it was Gmail.